# Plotting multivariate functions

Tags: plotting

So I have a function

```
\[Phi] = 4*ArcTan[(v*t)/Sinh[vt/Sqrt[1 - v^2]]];
```

And am trying to plot using

```
Plot[\[Phi], {x, -Pi, Pi}]
```

But so far seem to be having no look as it creates a pair of empty axes. What is going on here?

Comment: Your function depends on `t,v, vt` and you try to plot over `x`. Perhaps there is a typo inside definition and `vt`shoud be `v*t`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming a typo ( `vt`equals `v*t`) and assuming missing parameter value for `v`:

```
With [{v = .1},Plot[4*ArcTan[(v*t)/Sinh[v t/Sqrt[1 - v^2]]], {t, 0, 10}]]
```

[image]